# How to resize the image width and height with same quality in Corona SDK?

Tags: image, lua, resize, coronasdk

I want to re-size the image for example say 1000 * 1000 to 100 * 100. And I want to display full image after resizing it. Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scale display objects in Corona either use the scale() command or manipulate the xScale and yScale properties:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/node/2452

Note however that the scaling will look best if the image sticks to power of two divisions. That is, 1/2 size, 1/4 size, etc.

For fast animations (eg. the object transitions away over half a second) the exact scaling you describe would look fine, but otherwise I'm wondering why you would want to do that in Corona (as opposed to scaling the image in Photoshop and simply having a smaller image to begin with.)

Comment: How to get object width and height after scaling the object

Comment: The easiest way is to know it in the first place. That is, you knew the dimensions when you loaded the image and you know what scaling was applied.

Comment: That said, you can also use parameters like contentBounds, contentHeight, and contentWidth http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectcontentbounds http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectcontentheight

Comment: I doubt this is the answer. The user wants to resize the actual photo and save it with lower pixel size, scale is just changing it for display.

Comment: *shrug* he's had four years to clarify

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best to create an image of a larger size than you'd like to display. This will preserve the quality. For example you have an image with dimensions of 100x100 and you'd like it to display as a 20x20 image. Do the following:

```
local IMAGE = display.newImageRect("IMAGE.png", 20, 20)
```